# Moving tmux pane to window

Tags: tmux

How do I move an existing pane into another window in **tmux** when I have multiple windows, and vice versa?

I'm coming from **screen**, where I can switch to the pane and then switch windows until I get to the one I want; **tmux** does not seem to allow this.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

The command to do this is [`join-pane`](http://man.openbsd.org/tmux.1) in tmux 1.4.

> ```
> join-pane [-dhv] [-l size | -p percentage] [-s src-pane] [-t dst-pane]  
>     (alias: joinp)
>     Like split-window, but instead of splitting dst-pane and creating
>     a new pane, split it and move src-pane into the space.  This can
>     be used to reverse break-pane.
> ```

To simplify this, I have these binds in my `.tmux.conf` for that:

```
# pane movement
bind-key j command-prompt -p "join pane from:"  "join-pane -s '%%'"
bind-key s command-prompt -p "send pane to:"  "join-pane -t '%%'"
```

The first grabs the pane from the target window and joins it to the current, the second does the reverse.

You can then reload your tmux session by running the following from within the session:

```
$ tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: I'm trying this method but when I put your code into my .tmux.conf file and do Ctrl-b, j, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: You need at least 2 windows open, with a couple panes in each: then hit `Prefix+s` and *enter the window name at the prompt* to send the pane to that window...

Comment: I am still not having any luck with this, nothing happens. I get the feeling tmux is not reading the .tmux.conf file because it does not respond at all to Ctrl-b, j or Ctrl-b, s. (these are the only 2 lines in the config file)

Comment: Have you reloaded the .conf file after creating it? Ctrl-b r?

Comment: Yes, I have. it works is I manually enter the commands breakp or joinp, your config just does not seem to have any effect on my system.

Comment: I left the first comment line in it, would that be causing any problems?

Comment: No - comments have no effect. Perhaps edit your question and include more information (version number, distro etc) - that might help diagnose your second issue. Glad you got it working though...

Comment: How do I find my tmux version? -V, -v, --version, etc.. don't seem to work. It's the latest version on Debian 6.

Comment: If the -V switch doesn't work, it is pre-1.4. Build your own current version and you will be good to go...

Comment: Found it, I'm running 1.3-2. Ill try updating.

Comment: @mrlanrat I find that you must prefix the window number with a colon. See my answer below.

Comment: Note that this process: join pane, break pane, will remove any window-renames you've done.  Any way around that?

Comment: Great. Since i'm using `h j k l` to move "vi style" between panes, i used `>` and `<` to "send pane" and "bring pane" from windows.

Comment: What does the '%%' refer to?

Comment: @oligofren `'%%'` is a template literal that receives the first user input.

Answer (score 237):

join-pane is the answer. I too was having problems with my attempts to use it based on the tmux documentation. I discovered that the `-t` and `-s` switches seem to accept `[session]:window` and not `[session:]window`. That is to say that specifying the session is optional, but including the `:` is mandatory.  (I am using tmux 1.5)

Therefore, in order to add a pane to the current window and place window 1 into the pane, the command would be (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or whatever your bind key is, followed by)...

```
:join-pane -s :1
```

You can then break them apart with break-pane which by default is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> If you want to bind it to a shortcut, I suggest NOT overriding a default binding like s, because down the road you will look on the internet for an answer that involves choose-session and it will not work on your system. Notice that break-pane is bound to <kbd>!</kbd> and <kbd>@</kbd> is right next to it and not bound to anything by default. For that reason I suggest this binding...

```
bind-key @ command-prompt -p "create pane from:"  "join-pane -s ':%%'"
```

Alternately, to have an interactive chooser...

```
bind-key   @ choose-window 'join-pane -h -s "%%"'
bind-key C-@ choose-window 'join-pane    -s "%%"'
```

Alternately, to always join the most recently visited window...

```
bind-key @ join-pane -h -s !
```

NOTE: The `-h` causes it to stack the panes horizontally (with a vertical split) as opposed the default behavior which is the reverse.

The most important thing is that your LEARN whatever you choose to shortcut. Because if you just set it and forget it, you will be gimped when you find yourself on a foreign server. And let's face it, the most important thing a  terminal multiplexer gives you is reliable sessions on remote servers.

This completes my conversion from GNU Screen to Tmux. I'll never look back.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'd been missing the ':' as well...thanks for this.

Comment: I got 2 down votes on this recently with no comments suggesting why. That's just rude and anti-FOSS culture.

Comment: documentation doesn't talk about colons at all!  Nice one

Comment: Using the dot syntax is what helped me `window.pane` for example `join-pane -s 1.0` to move pane 0 in window 1 into the current window. More details at https://maciej.lasyk.info/2014/Nov/19/tmux-join-pane/

Comment: As of tmux 2.1, the `:` apparently isn't required anymore (e.g., just do `:join-pane -s 1`). Maybe that was a bug in earlier versions

Comment: @JonnyRaa in `man tmux`, under "COMMANDS", a few paragraphs down, "target-window (or src-window or dst-window) specifies a window in the form session:window."

Comment: just to add a bit more documentation, it goes to another level aswell where you can use `.` as in `[session:]window[.pane]` to specify which pane of a window to take... only needed for multiple pane windows and (perhaps this is newer tmux) you can omit session in this case aswell

Comment: This is wonderful but it seems you got some ideas for [revision 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/30576/revisions) from [toupeira's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140002) below, in which case an explicit acknowledgement would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 77):

I think I like what I've been using for moving panes to their own window better. I use

```
break-pane -t :
```

I figured it out through experimentation, but it seems to work very well. You can keybind or alias it easily, no scripting required.

Comment: +1. I tend to use this much more often than `join-pane`.

Comment: just wow.......

Comment: This is the answer for moving a Pane to its own separate Window. Thank you.

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: This makes most sense! `join-pane` swapped my pane instead

Answer (score 38):

#### Key binding

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>!</kbd> would *break* the active pane into a new window **and** switch to it.

Where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> is the default [prefix](http://man.openbsd.org/tmux#prefix) for [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux).

#### Details

The `tmux` command this key executes is [`break-pane`](http://man.openbsd.org/tmux#prefix) (alias: `breakp`) as implemented in [`cmd-break-pane.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/cmd-break-pane.c#L49) and bound as default in [key-bindings.c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/key-bindings.c#L197) as seen in [`list-keys`](http://man.openbsd.org/tmux#list-keys) (alias: `lsk`) command output:

```
bind-key    -T prefix       !                 break-pane
```

Answer (score 22):

After looking through the other answers and perusing the tmux man page I settled on the following bindings for now:

```
bind-key S choose-window 'join-pane -v -s "%%"'
bind-key V choose-window 'join-pane -h -s "%%"'
```

This will let you interactively select the window to join, and mirrors my lowercase `s`/`v` bindings to create new vertical/horizontal splits. If anybody knows how to select individual panes instead of windows let me know.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. Unfortunately the `-v` and `-h` do not create vertical and horizontal "splits" respectively. They create vertical and horizontal "**stacked panes**" respectively. (That is to say that vertically stacked panes have a horizontal split.) So you have to train your brain that way. Also `-v` is the default, so I'd leave that out and only put the `-h` in there so that your `~/.tmux.conf` acts as a cheat sheet for you to look at.

Comment: I like this better than the other answers for "opposite of break-pane".  Having broken a pane free into its own window temporarily, later I want to send it back to one of the older windows and this handles that gracefully.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to type the pane identifier into a prompt, you can also use

```
bind-key j "join-pane -s !"
```

which will join the last active pane/window to the current window.

Comment: Which version are you using?  I'm getting `unknown command: join-pane -s !` with 1.6.

Comment: Using 2.0 here, but just putting the line into the conf without quotes seems to work fine. `bind-key j join-pane -s !`

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to change your key bindings.

Whilst the pane you wish to move has focus, type *Prefix* then `:join-pane -t :1` where `1` is whatever the destination window's number is in the same session. You can move it to another session by prepending its name like `project:3`. For me `join-pane` tab-autocompletes from `j`.

Add an `-h` or `-v` switch to the command to set the orientation of the new split created in the destination, or just go to it and *Prefix* + <kbd>space</kbd> to rearrange.

Answer (score 0):

here is the `bring pane from` as a `fzf-tmux` function.

just put this in some file:

```bash
function bring_pane() {
    windows=$(
        tmux list-windows -F "#{window_active} #{window_index} #{window_name}" | sort -r | awk '{print $2 " : " $3}' \
            | fzf-tmux -p --border-label="Bring pane" | awk '{print $1}' | sort -r
    )
    if [ -n "$windows" ]; then
        echo $windows | xargs -n1 -I {i} tmux join-pane -s {i}
    fi
}
```

Then in your tmux config source it:

```bash
bind-key i run-shell "source ~/.tmux/functions.sh && bring_pane"
```