# How do I cycle through panes inside a window in tmux like in screen?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, tmux, configuration

I thought [Moving tmux pane to window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/tmux-move-window-to-pane) was the same question but it doesn't seem to be.

Coming from using GNU screen regularly, I'm looking for tmux to do the same things. On of the things I do regularly is have a couple of different windows open, one with some code open in vim, and a couple of terminals windows open to test the code, and sometimes a window or two for various other things. I split the screen vertically and will often have the vim window in the top pane and then one of the other windows in the bottom bane.

The main commands I then use are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> to rotate among the panes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>n</kbd> to rotate between the windows within a pane. For instance, with vim in the top pane, I switch to the bottom pane and then rotate through the other terminals, doing whatever I need. The screen stays split the whole time.

The problem is I can't find comparable capability to screen's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>n</kbd> in tmux. Switching windows seems to not work inside a pane, but jumps entirely. If the screen is split the only two options seem to be to jump to some window that isn't split and then split it or to do a sub-split of a pane. Neither are what I was looking for.

Suggestions (besides just sticking with screen)?

Comment: Your terminology is a little confusing. In `tmux` a window can be split into multiple panes. Are you trying to cycle between panes in a window with a keybind?

Comment: I was trying to follow the nomenclature of the tools, but I admit it is confusing. I know how to change focus from one pane to another. What I'm trying to find out is how to cycle what is displayed in a particular pane without otherwise changing the layout.

Comment: So to move content from one pane to another? Are you looking for `swap-pane`? If you are looking to emulate screen's `Ctrl-a n`, then the tmux equivalent is `Ctrl-b n`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*tmux* and *screen* have different models so there is no exact equivalent.

In *screen* terms, a split lets you display multiple windows at the same time. `next` (`C-a n`) rotates windows through the active part of the split; this lets you rotate “hidden” windows through the active region of the split.

In *tmux* terms, a split divides a window into one or more panes. Each part of a split window is an individual pane, panes are never hidden (if a window is  selected (visible) all its panes are, too), and a pane can only be used in a single split of one window (a pane can not be in multiple windows, and it can not be in multiple splits of the same window). There are commands to move panes around in (or between) windows, but not in an identical way to `next` in *screen*.

---

You could use a binding like the following to arrange a similar effect:

```
bind-key C-n swap-pane -s :+.top \; rotate-window -Ut :+
```

You will probably want to put this in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, but you can just type/paste it after <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> to bind it in your current server instance.

To use the binding, pick your “main window”, split it, create a “pane container” window immediately after the “main window”, then use the binding to rotate any pane in the “main window” among the group in the “pane container” window.

Here is how you might create the setup:

- Pick a window to use as your “main window”. Start (e.g.) *Vim* in it.
- Split your “main window” into two panes.

  E.g. <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> (`:split-window`)

  You can use this pane as your testing window (or log viewer, or whatever).
- Create a new window (the “pane container”) immediately after your main window.

  E.g. <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> (`:new-window`)

  It is important that no other window gets between the indexes of the “main window” and the “pane container” window (`+` in the window specifiers used in the bound commands means “the next higher numbered window”).
- Split this window into a number of panes. To rotate through three panes, split this window into two panes (the third pane is the one in the “main window”).

  Maybe you need a shell for *git*, and a shell for running a database interface. Put each in a separate pane in this “pane container” window.
- Switch back to your “main window”. Select the pane that you want to “rotate out”.

  You can use <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to move among the panes.
- Invoke the binding to swap the current pane with the first pane in “pane container” window and (“behind the scenes”) rotate the panes inside the “pane container” window (so that the next time you run the binding, the first command swaps with the “next” pane in the sequence).

  <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> (the binding use C-n, but you could change this to whatever you like).
- To scroll backwards through the panes, you can use the below:

```
bind-key C-p swap-pane -s :+.bottom \; rotate-window -Dt :+
```

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation and your suggested binding does appear to at least replicate the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Excuse me, how might one full size a pane and then swap back to the previous arrangement

Comment: @JamesAndino: *tmux* 1.8 has `resize-pane -Z` (by default, bound to Prefix + z) that temporarily “zooms” a pane to be the full size of the window. For version prior to 1.8 there was no built-in way to do it; others have crafted scripted solutions from other built-in commands (e.g. some of the answers to the SU question [“Maximizing” a pane in tmux](http://superuser.com/q/238702/14827)).

Comment: ty, compiled and loaded

Comment: I believe `C-b o` cycles panes.

Comment: My tmux 2.8 has this default key binding: `bind-key    -T prefix       o                 select-pane -t :.+`

Answer (score 72):

I believe what you are looking for is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+(<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>).  Those will allow you to move between the panes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I wasn't very clear. I've figure out how to move from panel to panel. In tmux Ctrl b + o functions about the same as Ctrl a + Tab in screen. What I'm looking for is the equivalent functionality as screen's Ctrl a + n.

Comment: @FooBar how about `Ctrl-b+{` or `Ctrl-b+}`? That is about as close as I can find to that functionality.  Pane's aren't done the same way in tmux as they are handled in screen.

Comment: I often have trouble focusing the highlighted pane, say I have two panes, I often press `^b↑`. How do I then actually focus the highlighted pane such that another `↑` will be captured by the shell, not tmux?

Comment: not in my case. that just does resize the current pane

Comment: @KansaiRobot what shell are you running?

Comment: I managed to do it. it was just a case of when exactly you pressed the arrows

Answer (score 24):

use `bind -r`, so you can press the `prefix` once, then other keys in a sequence to locate your pane. The timeout could be adjusted by `repeat-time`. Check `man tmux`

```
bind -r Tab select-pane -t :.+
```

If you prefer `hjkl`,

```
bind -r h select-pane -L
bind -r j select-pane -D
bind -r k select-pane -U
bind -r l select-pane -R
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small conf that allows you to move to another pane or windows by using the shortcuts `ALT` or `SHIFT` + `arrow`. No need to use the prefix key. It's confortable!

```
## NAVIGATION: ############################

# Switch panes 
# Usage: "ALT+arrow keys" (without prefix key)
# from https://gist.github.com/spicycode
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D
 
# Switch windows 
# usage: "SHIFT+arrow" (without prefix key)
bind -n S-Left  previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window
```

You could also be interested by the following code that allow panes navigation by mouse. (usage: key prefix + m to turn on, M to turn it off)

```
## MOUSE CONTROL: #########################
set -g mode-mouse off
set -g mouse-resize-pane off
set -g mouse-select-pane off
set -g mouse-select-window off

# Toggle mouse on 
bind m \
    set -g mode-mouse on \;\
    set -g mouse-resize-pane on \;\
    set -g mouse-select-pane on \;\
    set -g mouse-select-window on \;\
    display 'Mouse: ON'
    
# Toggle mouse off
bind M \
    set -g mode-mouse off \;\
    set -g mouse-resize-pane off \;\
    set -g mouse-select-pane off \;\
    set -g mouse-select-window off \;\
    display 'Mouse: OFF'
```

this config has been tested on Tmux 1.6 to 1.9.

Answer (score 5):

Put the following code in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
# cycle prev/next pane
bind -n S-right select-pane -t :.+
bind -n S-left select-pane -t :.-
```

Reload config, then you can press (directly without prefix key) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to cycle panes in clockwise direction, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to cycle in reversed direction.

Tested in Tmux 2.8.

---

In case you don't want to edit the config, <kbd>prefix</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is the default key binding for clockwise cycle. I occasionally found this key binding, then I get the command from `tmux list-keys` and use it for my own key bindings:

```
bind-key    -T prefix       o                 select-pane -t :.+
```

Answer (score 3):

*This answers gives you two panes, where both panes hold the same set of windows, but each pane can switch between windows independently.*

The tmux approach is to use **three** sessions:

- an outer session for the **panes**,
- an inner session for the **windows** (you can attach to this from one pane),
- a secondary **view** onto the inner session (for the other pane).

Yes this is [UNIX philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well) gone mad.  Let's get started:

```
# Create a session to hold the multiple windows
$ tmux new-session -s inner

    <Ctrl-b> c   to create a few windows, run some things

    <Ctrl-b> d   to detach, but leave it running

# Create a session to hold multiple panes (the view)
$ tmux new-session -s outer

    <Ctrl-b> "   to split

# Open the inner session in the current (bottom) pane
$ unset TMUX ; tmux attach -t inner
```

Now you can switch to the top pane and open Vim as usual.  To cycle through the windows in the inner session (the lower pane) you will need to use <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>.

> Aside: That is a bit unwieldy but you could always change the prefix of the outer session, e.g. to <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>, like this:
>
> ```
> <Ctrl-b> :set-option prefix C-a
> ```
>
> Then it would just be <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> to cycle the inner windows, and <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> to cycle the outer panes.

OK now, instead of opening Vim in the top pane, let's connect again to your inner session.  Quit vim, and this time use a `new-session` command (notably with `-t` not `-s`):

```
$ tmux new-session -t inner
```

Voila!  You can now cycle through windows on both the top and bottom panes.

The reason we must use `new-session -t` the second time is that if we were to simply do `attach -t` again, then the top and bottom panes would be synchronized, always showing the same window, which is not what you want.  To let this pane move through windows independently of the other pane, we create a new "view" session but connect its back end directly to the existing session that holds the windows.  This is also known as "[grouped sessions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24288/33967)".  (By the way, that link also suggests using `[un]link-window` to move windows between sessions.)

Of course for symmetry, you could have run `tmux new-session -t inner` in the bottom pane too, instead of `attach`.  In that case you would be running 4 instances of tmux (plus one more tmux process for the server)!