# tmux with more terminals than panes

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

'm trying to migrate to tmux from gnu-screen. There is one feature in screen that I can't figure out how to do in tmux. Specifically, with screen I have one window and I can split that into multiple panes and, most importantly, I can have more pseudoterminals than panes. For example, I'll often have two panes but will frequently swap between three different terminals.

In tmux, I seem to always have just as many pseudoterminals as I do panes. What set up and commands will give me the behavior I like in screen in tmux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual page says you can't do this.  Quoting:

> A session is a single collection of pseudo terminals under the management
>   of tmux.  Each session has one or more windows linked to it.  **A window
>   occupies the entire screen and may be split into rectangular panes, each
>   of which is a separate pseudo terminal** (the pty(4) manual page documents
>   the technical details of pseudo terminals).  Any number of tmux instances
>   may connect to the same session, and any number of windows may be present
>   in the same session.  Once all sessions are killed, tmux exits.

Comment: I came across this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53154/how-do-i-cycle-through-panes-inside-a-window-in-tmux-like-in-screen?rq=1), but haven't had time to test it.  I will updated later.